# ECMAScript Callback method executed after PreSaveAction method

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

My requirement is to get value from another list and set it to SharePoint list form and then save the item.

I wrote ECMAScript and PreSaveAction(). However, PreSaveAction() return true is executed before ECMAScript call back method, which is why my field value is not saved when I click Save button. Please note that my call back function has no error and I get correct value in alert. I don't know where I am doing wrong. Below is my code for you reference.

```
function PreSaveAction() 
    { 
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(GetTotalAmtAlloted, "sp.js");
        return true;**//This line will execute before my callback function onListItemsLoadSuccess or onQueryFailed execute. Because of this, my field value not able to save it.**

    }


 function GetTotalAmtAlloted()
    {
        var clientContext = null;
        var web = null;
        var vID;

        clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        web = clientContext.get_web();
        var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Investment");
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

        var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='InvestmentSubject' /><Value Type='Text'>abc</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

        camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);

        listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(listItems);
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onListItemsLoadSuccess,onQueryFailed);//After this line "return true" in PreSaveAction() will execute and then CallBackMethods will run.

}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess(sender, args) 
{
  $("input[Title='Total Amount']").val("1000");

}

 function onQueryFailed(sender,args)
 {
  alert("error");
 }
```

Comment: It should return `true` right away since the first line just registers an event handler, so there is nothing wrong there. Why are you using `ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded`? I'm sure `SP.js` is already loaded when you click the save button. Please, clarify your question as to what you try to achieve since what you have right now doesn't make that much sense.

Comment: Hi Daniel, When my NewForm.aspx opens, User select "Investment Type" from dropdown. User click save button. Now, in PreSaveAction(), I will fetch value for "Total Amount" hidden field from another list based on "Investment Type" selected by user. After I click save this "Total Amount" field should also get save. However, my call back method which actually gets the value from another list execute after "return true" in PreSaveAction().

Comment: JavaScript is synchronous. When you fetch your data from the other list you perform an **asynchronous** operation. If you want to let that finish before you `return true` you must handle it in another way. Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes Daniel. I am trying to achieve what you have mentioned. Can you show me the way to handle it?

Comment: Any success with my proposed answer?

Comment: Thanks Daniel for precise explanation. I didn't got the output though. However, when I try to debug in Developer tool, The break point is getting fadeout. Probably some issue. When I remove your code, break points works fine. Are you missing anything in your code?

Comment: Not that I can see. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No Daniel. I am not getting any error. To check this, I tried putting breakpoint in developer tool but breakpoint is getting fadeout (showing warning sign on breakpoint)

Comment: There is no output anywhere in the code.

Comment: $("input[Title='Total Amount']").val("1000"); will assign value to field and then PreSaveAction() will return true via promise.done(). I should see Total Amount field with value 1000 after save.

Comment: Well, you are not getting the value from the field you've just fetched. You are just setting the value `1000` to whatever element on the **current** page that matches the CSS selector. You have to get the value from the `listItems` in your success function.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Above code was only a sample. My real code for success call back method is getting listItem object and getting value in gInvestmentAmount  variable and then assigning it like this:-$("input[Title='Total Amount Alloted']").val(gInvestmentAmount);

Comment: Finally, I end up fixing my issues via Javascript SPService. Thanks Daniel for your new way to handle synchronous and asynchronous issues.

Answer (score -1):

You are performing an asynchronous function call but expect it to act synchronous. Instead, you have to wait for your asynchronous function to finish before your  `PreSaveAction` can return `true`.

Since you're using jQuery, this can easily be achieved using the deferred/promise that jQuery provides.

```
function PreSaveAction() { 
    //Get the promise from the function
    var promise = GetTotalAmtAlloted();

    //This is run when the promise is resolved
    promise.done(function(){
        return true;
    });

    //This is run when the promise is rejected
    promise.fail(funtion(){

    });
}


function GetTotalAmtAlloted() {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    var clientContext = null;
    var web = null;
    var vID;

    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = clientContext.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle("Investment");
    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();

    var q = "<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='InvestmentSubject' /><Value Type='Text'>abc</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>";

    camlQuery.set_viewXml(q);

    listItems = list.getItems(camlQuery);

    //An object to pass to the success and failure handlers
    var data = {d: d, list: listItems}
    clientContext.load(listItems);

    //Execute the query and pass the data with our deferred object
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(data, onListItemsLoadSuccess), Function.createDelegate(data, onQueryFailed));//After this line "return true" in PreSaveAction() will execute and then CallBackMethods will run.

    //Return a promise that can either resolve or reject depending on if the async function is a success or failure
    return d.promise();    
}

function onListItemsLoadSuccess() {
    //Access the listItems
    var listItems = this.list;

    //Do something with the list items

    //On success, resolve the promise
    this.d.resolve();
}

function onQueryFailed() {
    //On failure, reject the promise
    this.d.reject("Something went wrong!");
    alert("error");
}
```

Comment: This is just wrong. `promise.done(function(){ return true; });` will just end the inner function, not PreSaveAction.

Comment: How is it wrong? `return true;` is the equivalent of wrapping a `true` value inside a `resolve` of a promise. It will end the function.

Comment: It will end the pormise resolution function, passing a true resolution down the chain, but that will never return to the calling function, PreSaveAction here.